# Can't sign in with correct Email address and Password with Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I create one web App for graduation research (developed with Vue.js, vue-router). I'm using Firebase Authentication to sign in. Even though using the correct Email Address and password, I can't sign in and the site redirect from 'localhost:8080/signin' to 'localhost:8080/signin?' .

This is developed with Vue(2.6.10) and firebase.

```
(ellipsis)
input(type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" v-model="email")#MailAddress
(ellipsis)
input(type="password" placeholder="password" v-model="password")#Password
(ellipsis)
```

```
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  name: "Signin",
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(
          () => {
            alert("Success");
            this.$router.push("/");
          },
          err => {
            alert(err.message);
          }
        );
    }
  }
};
```

I expect to redirect to 'localhost:8080/'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

In my Vue component:

```
import firebase from '../database';

async signIn () {
  let result = await firebase.signIn(this.email, this.password);
  if (result.message) {
    this.error = result.message;
  } else {
    // Go to your route
  }
}
```

In my database file:

```
const database = firebase.initializeApp(config);

database.signIn = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggest. Anyway I could fix my problem.